# How do you detect voice channel streaming? (discord.js)

Tags: discord.js

Is there any event for when users stream directly in the voice channel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
client.on("voiceStateUpdate", (oldVoiceState, newVoiceState) => {
    if (!newVoiceState) {return false};
    if (newVoiceState.streaming) {
        console.log(`${newVoiceState.member.user.tag} is streaming.`);
    };
});
```

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceState